# Express $f + g$ and $f\cdot g$ as compositions involving $f$ and $g$ and various of other functions.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Here is the question:

> [image]

And here is the various functions we have been looking at (I answered all the question given below):

> [image]

And here is the definition of $\mathcal{F}$: $$\mathcal{F} = \{ \textbf{all continuous functions } \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \}.$$

Also, we will use the notation $p_{n}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $p_{n}(x) = x^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where we take $0 \in \mathbb{N}.$ Now, since $p_{1} = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$, my work in problem $I$ tells us that $p_{1} \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathrm{const}_{y} \in \mathcal{F}$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

So, could anyone help me in the solution of problem 5? For (a), I am wondering how can I express  $f + g$ and $f\cdot g$ as compositions involving $f$ and $g$ and **various of other functions given in Problem I.** Also, I do not know how to prove (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, if $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ are continuous then

$(f \times g): \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to   \Bbb R \times \Bbb R $ given by $(f \times g)(x,y)=(f(x), g(y))$ is also continuous.

This should be one the other functions you've looked at already.

Also defining $p: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by $p(x,y)=x+y$, this $p$ is continuous as well, presumably this is well-known too.

Then $$f+g = p \circ (f \times g) \circ \Delta\tag{1}$$ The right hand side maps $x$ to $(x,x)$ first, and $f \times g$ maps that to $(f(x),g(x))$ and $p$ maps this to $f(x)+g(x)$ which equals $(f+g)(x)$ by definition.

So if $f,g \in \mathcal{F}$ (so they are continuous) then $f \times g$ also is and $f+g$ is as a composition of continuous maps under $(1)$, showing the first part of $(b)$

Multplication is the same except $p$ has to be replaced by another continuous map.

Comment: For line (2). No I did not look at this function before.

Comment: @Emptymind you should. It's continuous because the compositions with the two projections are continuous. What text are you using?

Comment: Does $f \times g$ for you has the same meaning of $f.g$ defined in the question?

Comment: We defined the direct product of 2 sets by the universal mapping property, does this what you mean by  $f \times g,$ the unique continuous function that makes the diagram commutes?

Comment: @Emptymind yes, it's that function that makes a diagram commute. Not $f \cdot g$. I gave the definition..

Comment: Should not we have $p_{1} + p_{2}$ in $(1)$ as we need the sum of the 2 projections?

Comment: And then for $f.g$ we will just have $p_{1}.p_{2}$ .... am I correct?

Comment: @Emptymind the projections aren’t needed. The addition map is itself a map with arguments and a single value. You still need to show the addition continuous.

Comment: Oh, so you mean that your $p$ is not the projection function?

Comment: @Emptymind it's the *plus*-function.

Comment: Now, for $f.g$ do we need the projection function 2 times as I mentioned above $p_{1}.p_{2}$?

Comment: @Emptymind no just the $m: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by $m(x,y)=x\cdot y$, the multiplication function,

Comment: So why is this question complexifying the definition of $+$ and $.$ like that? what does it want to teach us?

Comment: @Emptymind that the closure of $\mathcal{F}$ under addition follows from the continuity of $p$ plus that of a few standard functions $\Delta$ and the Cartesian product map $f \times g$. A smooth way to prove continuity of $f+g$ without doing extra work.